# Are there keyboard shortcuts for manipulating windows in Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, keyboard-shortcuts, window-manager

I'm looking specifically for shortcuts that resize, move and otherwise let me avoid using the mouse for manipulating application windows. Bonus points for shortcuts that let me move windows between different monitors.

Comment: rat poison?????

Comment: @Troggy: Yeah, death to the mouse. I used to use a window manager on Linux called rat poison. Everything ran full screen. Virtual desktops and keyboard shortcuts all the way. A little extreme but it worked better than I expected. Here's a link: http://www.nongnu.org/ratpoison/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Although not "offical" shortcuts <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> accesses the system menu so:

- Resize:  <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>
- Move:  <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>
- Minimize:  <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>
- Maximize:  <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>
- Restore:  <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>

Comment: I didn't know about these and they are fantastic! When resizing and moving it goes in ~10 pixel blocks but if you hold down CTRL you get to move things a pixel at a time. Thanks.

Comment: alt+space, x is a godsend.
Just be careful not to hit 'c' instead of 'x'.

Answer (score 2):

Not directly shortcuts, but I use [Enso](http://www.humanized.com/enso/) to:

- minimize
- maximize
- close
- quit
- open with

Among other things.

What I love from this is exactly what you're asking. Not having to take my hands out of the keyboard to do this.

It doesn't support "move to monitor" though

Comment: Enso looks extremely interesting. A faster Start Menu? Sold!